# Python: Generic way to use unpacked tuple as (dict) key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

In python we can unpack function arguments, so that we get the individual elements:

```
def printAll(*args):
    print(args, *args)  # packed and unpacked version respectively
printAll(1)  # (1,) 1
printAll(1, 2)  # (1, 2) 1 2
```

However, I would like to define a function that (among some other things) accesses a certain container (say a dict) with some of the arguments.
**The dict is predefined and cannot be modified!**
I run into the following trouble:

```
# e.g. d is a dict with
#    d[1] = 1 <- key is scalar
#    d[1, 2] = 3 <- key is tuple
def accessDict(name, *args):
    print('Hello', name)
    d[args]
    # d[*args] what I'd need, but it's invalid syntax
accessDict('foo', 1)  # should give 1 but gives KeyError because args is (1,) not 1
accessDict('foo', 1, 2)  # should give 3
```

One alternative is to add:

```
if len(args) == 1:
    return d[args[0]]
```

But I feel there should be a more elegant way to do this...

Comment: A tuple and a scalar are fundamentally different objects. A tuple (even a len-1 tuple) is a sequence, while a scalar is a single value. What you have now is fine, and clarity is best when you have dictionaries with non-standardised keys. You could change your dict key to `(1,)`.

Comment: Not if it's not my code that dictates the keys ;)

Comment: Actually, just because you define your dictionary keys in a particular way doesn't change this fact: `A tuple and a scalar are fundamentally different objects.` :)

Comment: The whole point is that the containers I am using may have different types of keys. This is determined by code that I cannot modify. My task is to find an elegant way to provide access to these kinds of containers with one or more keys. Maybe it helps to think of the dict creation in this way: `d=dict(); d[1] = 1; d[1,2] = 3`
Here it becomes clear that one or more key elements translates to tuple or scalar, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way would be to have consistent keys with something like:

```
d = {(1,): 1, (1, 2): 3}
```

If you cannot, but you will need to process many operations on that dict, it could make sense to pre process it:

```
d = {1: 1, (1, 2): 3}
dd = { (k if isinstance(k, tuple) else (k,)): v for k, v in d.items() }
```

If you need to use if only a few times, then you can stick to your initial proposal:

```
def accessDict(name, *args):
    print('Hello', name)
    d[args if len(args) > 1 else d[args[0]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, as described in [SergeBallesta's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51539034/9209546), you should consider redefining your dictionary keys to be consistently tuples.

Otherwise, you can use `dict.get` to use a fallback:

```
d = {1: 1, (1, 2): 3}

def accessDict(name, *args):
    return d.get(args[0], d.get(args))

accessDict('foo', 1)     # 1
accessDict('foo', 1, 2)  # 3
```

If this is *really* the bottleneck, and one case is unlikely, you can use `try` / `except`:

```
def accessDict(name, *args):
    try:
        return d[args[0]]
    except KeyError:
        return d[args]
```

In my opinion, the last version is *most* Pythonic. If it quacks like a duck, it's a duck. No need to check for length / type / etc.

Comment: Nice, but the default should probably just be a `d[args[0]]`. But even then this is just a slightly less efficient way of the if/else access I propose, which you can also write as a one liner:
`def accessDict(*args):
        return d[args[0]] if len(args) == 1 else d[args]`

Comment: @mrclng, You may or may not be right about efficiency. I believe both solutions have O(1) complexity. I've updated to reflect the default.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, it's impossible to read. In my opinion, this is highly likely *not* to be a bottleneck. But, if it is, then sure the ternary operator may be the way to go, and less readable.

Comment: Sorry for the code-only comment, but yeah, the ternary operator is about 40% faster and in my opinion more explicit than the get method, which is still pretty nice but I had to look it up ;)

Comment: @mrclng, If speed is *really* an issue and one case is very rare, `try` / `except` would be the way forward.

Answer (score -2):

First of all python method arguments are by default tuple.

Your case, you cannot use arg as a dictionary key which does not exist as a key of the dictionary. so if you want to do so you need to extract each key from the tuple and assign it to your dictionary.

This code might help you.

```
d = {1: 1, (1, 2): 3}
def accessDict(name, *args):
   print('Hello', name)


 #So simple edit is
   for a in args:
       d[a] #1, 3 


accessDict('foo', 1) 
accessDict('foo', (1, 2))
```

Comment: You can absolutely use a whole `tuple` as a `dict` key. It may not be the desired program logic, but it's completely legal.

Comment: any hashable type can be used as a `dict` key

Comment: Yes, You can, my point was that if the key doesn't exist it will give the error for the particular dic object.